# Implementing JSX in Rust

Tags: reactjs, rust

As an exercise I have been trying to implement something like [JSX](https://facebook.github.io/jsx/) in Rust with all the added benefits of static typing of props. The idea is to implement the data structures to support this feature and then add a simple syntactic layer with macros. JSX has the following important concepts:

- Very similar to XML/HTML, it's a data structure that represents a tree, and the nodes of a tree are Elements.
- Element: a simple data structure that represents a node in the tree, it's main attributes are: Type (Div, P or a Custom), Props (the arguments) and it's children (a vec of Elements)
- Custom Components: they provide the ability to encapsulate an Element subtree inside a "function" i.e. they are functions that return Elements. I worked with the assumption of supporting this custom render functionality through the Element.type attribute (see impl below)
- Custom Components are represented as Elements with a special type attribute. After they run their "render" function, they are replaced by the contents of it's render function in the final tree.
- Once the whole tree is resolved (each custom element is "rendered") the tree will only contain Native Elements (i.e. dom elements), this is the final tree

  - The final tree can be rendered to string by traversing it

So, as a high level we could have:

```
create_element(
  Div,
  DivProps { id: "myId", class: "one two three", ..DivProps::default()}, 
  vec![   
    create_element(P, PProps { ..PProps::default()}, vec![
      "Hello" // Polymorphic
    ])
  ])
```

and then the idea is via macros provide the following syntax

```
<div id="myId" class="one two three">
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

One of the most problematic parts is that this naturally defines a data structure like this

```
struct Element<T, P>

where
 T: String for native dom elements or a custom struct for custom components,
 P: Any data structure
 {
  etype: T, 
  props: P,
  children: vec![Element<?, ?>]
}
```

I have been experimenting with several approaches but Im not super satisfied with the results and so this question is to find out if it is possible to do better or not.

This is the current implementation that Im most satisfied with

```
type Children = Vec<Rc<Render>>;

trait ElementParts {
    fn get_children(&self) -> Option<&Children>;
    fn get_tag(&self) -> String;
}


// Mostly for custom elements
trait Render: ElementParts + Debug + Display {
    // Dom elements don't have to render anything
    fn render(&self) -> Option<Rc<Render>> {
        None
    }

    // Tell whether it's a custom component that will render more things or not.
    fn should_render(&self) -> bool {
        true
    }

    // TODO Ideally this should be outside this trait
    // what bout if this is a standalong function
    // that acepts a T: RenderToString where RenderToString: Render
    // so, renderToString will have access to parts, render, should render, and anything else
    fn render_to_string(&self) -> String {
        if self.should_render() {
            match self.render() {
                Some(element) => element.render_to_string(),
                None => String::new(),
            }
        } else {
            format!("<{tag}>{}</{tag}>", self.render_children_to_string(), tag=self.get_tag())
        }
    }

    fn render_children_to_string(&self) -> String {
        if let Some(children) = self.get_children() {
            children.iter()
                .map(|child| child.render_to_string())
                .collect::<Vec<String>>()
                .join("\n")
        } else {
            String::new()
        }
    }
}




#[derive(Debug)]
struct Element<T: Debug + Clone + 'static, P: Debug + Clone + 'static> {
    etype: T,
    props: P,
    children: Children,
}



impl<P: Debug + Clone + 'static, T: Debug + Clone + 'static> Element<T, P> where Element<T, P>: Render {
    fn new(etype: T, props: P, children: Children) -> Rc<Render>
    {



        Rc::new(
            Element {
                etype: etype,
                children: children,
                props: props,
            }
        )
    }
}


impl<P: Debug + Clone + 'static, T: Debug + Clone + 'static> ElementParts for Element<T, P> {
    fn get_children(&self) -> Option<&Children> {
        Some(&self.children)
    }

    fn get_tag(&self) -> String {
        format!("{:?}", self.etype)
    }
}


impl<P: Debug + Clone + 'static, T: Debug + Clone + 'static> Display for Element<T, P> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "- {:?},  {:?}\n", self.etype, self.props).unwrap();
        for c in &self.children {
            write!(f, "  {}\n", c).unwrap();
        }

        write!(f, "\n")
    }
}


// Text node

impl ElementParts for String {
    fn get_children(&self) -> Option<&Children> {
        None
    }

    fn get_tag(&self) -> String {
        "TextNode".to_string()
    }

}

impl Render for String {
    fn should_render(&self) -> bool {
        false
    }

    fn render_to_string(&self) -> String {
        self.clone()
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Div;

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct DivProps {
    class: String,
}

impl Render for Element<Div, DivProps> {
    fn should_render(&self) -> bool {
        false
    }
}


#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct P;

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct PProps {
    class: String,
    text: Option<String>,
}

impl Render for Element<P, PProps> {
    fn should_render(&self) -> bool {
        false
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Name;

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct NameProps {
    show: bool,
    name: String,
}

impl Render for Element<Name, NameProps> {
    fn render(&self) -> Option<Rc<Render>> {
        // In here custom logic will come
        if !self.props.show {
            return Some(Element::new(
                    P,
                    PProps{class: String::new(), text: None,},
                    vec![
                        Rc::new("NOT_SHOWING".to_string()),
                    ]
                ))
        }


        Some(
            Element::new(
                Div,
                DivProps { class: "form-control".to_string()},
                vec![
                    Rc::new("SHOWING".to_string()),
                    Rc::new(self.props.name.clone())
                ]
            )
        )
    }
}

// And this is how I would use it

        let e = Element::new(Name, NameProps{ show: true, name: "Fran".to_string() }, vec![]);
        println!("{:?}", e);
        println!("{}", e.render_to_string());
```

Any ideas will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Already done in [yew](https://github.com/DenisKolodin/yew). Regardless, this question is far too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Im rejecting the new tag "webassembly" because my original intent was to create a server side templating engine with this mechanism so Im not interested in cross compiling it to browser running code for now.